# Kubernetes accessing one pod url from another

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes

I am creating a proxy server with node js and wants to proxy request coming to one pod to other pods in single node cluster of kubernetes. This is my node js code below  ,,,,

```js
const express = require("express");
const httpProxy = require("express-http-proxy");
const app = express();

const serviceone = httpProxy("serviceone:3000"); // I am using service names here but its not working

// Authentication
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  // TODO: my authentication logic
  console.log("Always.....");
  next();
});

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({ message: "Api Gateway Working" });
});

// Proxy request
app.get("/:data/api", (req, res, next) => {
  console.log("Request Recieved");
  serviceone(req, res, next);
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Api Gateway Running");
});
```

And these are my services.yml files

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: serviceone
  labels:
    app: serviceone
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: serviceone
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: serviceone
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: serviceone
        image: swa/serviceone
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: serviceone
spec:
  selector:
    app: serviceone
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
    nodePort: 31000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

What name should I use in http proxy so that it can proxy requests?

I have tried `serviceone:3000`, `http://serviceone:3000`, `http://localhost:3000` (won't work for different pods). Any help would be really appreciated

Edit - Node js apigateway pod

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apigateway
  labels:
    app: apigateway
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apigateway
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apigateway
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: apigateway
        image: swa/apigateway3
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: apigateway
spec:
  selector:
    app: apigateway
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
    nodePort: 31005
  type: LoadBalancer
```

In my node js application I changed urls to

```
const serviceone = httpProxy('serviceone.default.svc.cluster.local:3000');
```

by following this link https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#services
but still no luck

I am getting the error

> Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN servicethree.sock-shop.svc.cluster.local
> at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:66:26)

Comment: Can you give more information? Do you get any errors? What exactly does not work? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: node application cannot connect to serviceone it gives this error -Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN serviceone @DavidLosert

Comment: But I can access serviceone easily from my browser ,internal connection is the problem

Comment: And how are you creating pod/deployment/... that runs your nodejs code?

Comment: can you connect to your gateway if you use `kubectl port-forward` into it? what is the output from curl? If that goes well, check that dns works by running a container with an image such as "tutum/dnsutils" and running `dig serviceone` - it should answer with an A record with the service IP

Comment: I am fairly new to kubernetes can you be bit more clear ?@TomKlino

Comment: 1. `kubectl port-forward service/serviceone 3000:3000 &` and then `curl localhost:3000` - check the output. 2. `kubectl run -it --rm --image tutum/dnsutils pod -- dig kubernetes` - does it show A record with service IP?